# invalid cast exception.when casting from number,the value must be number less than infinity

Tags: c#, gridview

i am getting an invalid cast exception on this line

b = (int)dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value;

below is my code

```
    private void dataGridView2_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

 int a, b;
    if (dataGridView2.Rows.Count > 0 && e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex >= 0)
    {
        a = (int)dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value;
        b = (int)dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value;
        if (b > a)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("required quantity exceeds stock");
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The `NullReferenceException` is due to the fact that the passed `RowIndex` index value might be invalid in some situations. Within such cases, the `dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex]` will be doomed to utilize a null reference...

That `InvalidCastException` is probably due to that implicit casting, is which taken into account by you. You have mentioned nothing about the content of the datagridview cell, but if the casting logically would be possible in this scenario, you better to consider the static cast by `Convert.ToInt32()` method...

Finally below snippet might resolve your problem:

You need to handle the invalid values of the index to get rid of the exception.

```
private void dataGridView2_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
 {
        int a, b;

        if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 && e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex >= 0)
        {
            try
            {
                a = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value);
                b = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value);
                if (b > a)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("required quantity exceeds stock");
                }
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                //Or whatever you've planned for...
            }

        }
 }
```

Comment: how can i handle that invalid values?

Comment: @VrijSharma: You should generate a reasonable index, with due attention to logical functionality of your code, in the case of any exception.

Comment: :i have made following changes can u provide me with the solution?